# Order By Case of Dates is Slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

This query takes 200ms:

```
SELECT Date1, Date2 from Table1
ORDER BY Date1
```

Same if I order by Date2, it is fast and takes 200ms.

Date1 is DateTime Not Null

Date2 is DateTime Null

Date3 is DateTime Null

There is Index on Date1 and there is another index on Date2.
The table has 150 000 records.

If I order by a CASE statement, it takes 1.5seconds.

```
        SELECT 
    DateCase = 
    CASE 
    WHEN (Date1 IS NULL and Date2 IS NULL) THEN Date3
    CASE
WHEN (date1 is null and Date2 is not null) then Date2
WHEN (date1 is not null) then date1
ELSE DATE3

      from Table1
        ORDER BY DateCase
```

Any ideas how to speed up this query?

Comment: Try to visualize for a moment how this query would have to look up rows to order them consistently in all cases and you'll see why the optimizer has a hard time doing anything better than just calculating the date for all rows, then sorting, having no great use for the indexes at all. If you know more than the optimizer can know (like "`Date1` is actually mostly not `NULL` except for a few rows") you can consider some tricksy rewriting with temp tables, but otherwise the only real alternative would be to make this `CASE` available as a persisted column and index it separately.

Comment: For that query to work the server has to calculate all `DateCase` results, then sort them. This means it can't use any indexes that cover `Date1` or `Date2`. It will have to scan the entire table

Comment: I agree, I read about this and it is true. The question is ... can this be written in some other way or can this be optimized in other ways? Thanks.

Comment: @st_stefanov add a computed column that returns the first non-null date and create an index on top. You can use `COALESCE(Date1,Date2,Date3)` to get the first-non null value, but it's the *index* that will speed up processing

Comment: So if I need to have the Date that is not null in a specific order COALESCE will do that. E.g. I want it return Date1 if it is not null, then to check Date2 and return its value if it is not null and finally Date3. That will do it?

Comment: BTW - I removed my CASE statement and placed the COALESCE(Date1, Date2, Date3) and the performance didn't change, it was still the same. Just FYI if someone else reads it.

Comment: What the indexes will allow you to do is look up all rows quickly where `Date1 IS NULL` and order those by `Date2`. So you can do `WHERE Date1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Date1` and `WHERE Date1 IS NULL ORDER BY Date2`. Combining these efficiently would involve forcing a merge join, however, and I don't know if that can be done in one query without materializing into tables first. Indexing on a computed column would be *much* simpler, and faster, even if it eats extra storage.

Comment: make a permanent calculated field in your database based on your date logic, then index the field, then use that field in your query

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - yes, your solution worked. I added computed column and index it. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: How can `Date1` be null when its definition has `Not Null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By  Panagiotis Kanavos]
The solution was to create a computed column that adds the date I want to show on screen and it is created during Insert.
Then this column is indexed and the performance is good.

It might not be applicable in any case 
*(e.g. some tables could be huge, or can have multiple such cases which would lead to too many computed columns and indexes which might not be a good solution)*, 
but it works well for my case.

Answer (score -1):

ok try it,

```
SELECT DateCase = ISNULL(Date1,ISNULL(Date2,Date3)) 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY DateCase
```

Comment: I did small update, sorry, actually the case has 3 dates.

Comment: @st_stefanov the problem is using `DateCase` in the first place. `ISNULL` won't make anything run faster. The server will still have to perform a full scan to calculate the result values before sorting them

Comment: No performance improvement. It even took 3 seconds and was taking 1.5 before. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer